# Using @Transactional and @RequestMapping with RuntimeExceptions

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a bit of an oddity I'm hoping someone can shed some light on. I'm using `Hibernate 3.6.10` and `Spring Framework 3.1.2.RELEASE`.

I have a `@Controller` with methods annotated both `@RequestMapping` and `@Transactional`, which I know is a bad thing. We have to do it this way for now due to some tedious issues, but that's not really the issue here. All Lazy Loading works as expected within the Controller/Transactional.

These transactional methods call into a `@Service` with methods also marked with plain old `@Transactional`, which should keep everything in the same transaction, as `Propagation.REQUIRED` is the default. So far so good.

Now here's the befuddling tidbit. The `@Service` method throws an `XyzException` that extends `RuntimeException`, supposedly marking the transaction as rollback-only. By this logic, the one and only transaction that's being used should rollback and any attempt to handle the `XyzException` in the `@Controller` method without rethrowing before the transaction ends should result in another, less expected `RuntimeException` from Hibernate saying that the commit action failed due to the transaction being marked rollback-only. But it doesn't.

Instead, the transaction rolls back and the redirect (using POST, redirect, GET) successfully happens. No exceptions, no mess.

`So the question is, "What am I doing to make this work as it does?"`

I have an `OpenSessionInViewInterceptor` being used, so I thought maybe the transactions were not actually starting at the `@Controller` level. When I removed the `@Transactional`, however, the Lazy Load actions broke.

**- EDIT -**

So regardless of the OSIV nonsense, does it make sense that I'm able to handle an `XyzException` *inside* of the `@Transactional` method? I thought handled `RuntimeException`s inside of `@Transactional` methods that were not re-thrown would cause an error. Does it matter that the `@Transactional` method in question is the entry point (i.e. The first `@Transactional` method called)?

Comment: Did you add proxy interfaces to your controller and/or make sure you're using cgi-lib proxies after putting transactional on the controller methods?  This statement makes no sense: "I have an OpenSessionInViewInterceptor being used, so I thought maybe the transactions were not actually starting at the `@Controller` level. When I removed the `@Transactional`, however, the Lazy Load actions broke." the whole point of the interceptor is lazy loading works outside transactions.  Something is not set up correctly

Comment: Interesting. I'll take a look at the OSIV stuff again and make sure I didn't just overlook something. But that does make sense. Thanks!

Comment: don't mark controller methods as transactional, they should go on service classes or repositories

Comment: @NimChimpsky - See question: "which I know is a bad thing. We have to do it this way for now due to some tedious issues, but that's not really the issue here."

Comment: I have also faced this issue in my ealier project and my senior architect suggest the same thig which you are saying and i did that and after that now 2 years gone and application is working fine witout any issue. So you can handel that xyz exception inside @Transactional method..